# What do you call the latter part of a sentence which spans two pages?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, typography

Does the sentence fragment after the simulated pagebreak (the horizontal rule) have a specific term associated with it?

The start of a new paragraph includes an indent as shown here. Following the page-break that occurs hereabouts

---

the next line does not have an indent because it is part of the paragraph previously indented and not the beginning of a new paragraph. In HTML markup the single Paragraph element is split into two distinct Paragraph elements because the page Division is a parent container and each Paragraph may have one parent. A text-indent style is applied to all Paragraph elements by default and must be overridden by a named class applied to each fragment of the given type. I had been using the class name 'continuance' and then shortened that to 'c9e' for 'c' + 9 letters + 'e'. Is there a better (appropriate) name for this?

Comment: The typographical term _widow_ is related, although it generally only applies when the last line or two of a paragraph is left dangling on the page.

Comment: It is usually referred to as the **continuation** of the sentence.

Comment: @BraddSzonye Yes: a single word or line which goes over the page break and appears on its own at the top of a page is called an ***orphan***.

Comment: Also, FYI, in typography, paragraphs don't usually begin with an indent.

Comment: Apologies -- I initially misunderstood your question and improperly  voted to close it.

Comment: A "widow" is a single line at the top of a page when a paragraph is continued. An "orphan" is a single line at the bottom of the page that starts a paragraph. However, you're talking about the more general concept of a split paragraph, so those terms wouldn't fit. I'd just say the "continuation" of the paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any word used specifically for the continuation of a sentence or paragraph on a new page, though the more general term *continuation* works. In newspaper publishing, if an article starts on page 1 and continues on page 8 of the same edition, then page 8 is called a *jump page*: that's not what you're seeking but is thematically related, and if you're naming a CSS class, `jump` may be to your liking.